# for loop variable changing faster than changing css in setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I wrote this function to show flashing lights for a Simon game that I'm making. The flashing part is working, but I'm trying to play a sound every time `move.color.backgroundColor === colors[0]`, which is the highlighted color. The array is being looped over too fast for me to do this and I've been getting several different errors trying to solve this different ways, including all the sounds going off before the flashing has finished because the for loop variable finished looping faster than the variables showed flashing and then breaking the flashing function, even though its supposed to go at 1 second per loop. Here is the code -

```
game.computerMoves = {green, blue, blue, red, red, yellow};

const colors = [
 new Map([[green, "lime"], [yellow, "#FF6"], [blue, "dodgerblue"], [red,               "salmon"]]),
 new Map([[green, "green"], [yellow, "#CC0"], [red, "red"], [blue, "blue"]])
];

const sounds = {
 green : new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3"),
 blue : new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3"),
 yellow : new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3"),
 red : new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3")
};

game.computerMoves = {green, yellow, yellow, blue, red, red};

const colorFlashPeriod = 1000; // in ms

function showMoves() {
 let moveCounter = 0;
 const timeoutCount = game.computerMoves.length * 2;
 (function nextColor() {
   //this variable was finished looping before the backgroundColor finished flashing and it incremented faster than 1 second per loop. The flashing was shown at the correct times though, but I can't use this to set keys to add sounds
    let move = game.computerMoves[moveCounter >> 1];
    let c = game.computerMoves[moveCounter]
    console.log(c.id);
    move.style.backgroundColor = colors[(moveCounter++) & 1].get(move);
    if (moveCounter < timeoutCount) { setTimeout(nextColor, colorFlashPeriod) }
 })();
}
```

I also rewrote the showMoves function to flash lights into a working version here

```
function showMoves() {
  let i = 0;

const start = setInterval(function() {
  if (i >= game.computerMoves.length) {
      clearInterval(start);
      return;
  }

  const move = game.computerMoves[i];
  setLight(move, true);
  setTimeout(setLight.bind(null, move, false), 1000); //Using bind to preset arguments

  i++;
 }, 2000);
}

function setLight(color, isOn) {
  if(isOn){
sounds[color.id].play();
 }
   color.style.backgroundColor = isOn ? colors[0].get(color) : colors[1].get(color);
}
```

This version of is working how I want it to and playing the sounds at the right flashing times, but I'm not sure if its better designed than the showMoves function above it that I can't figure out how to get the sound to work on. I would appreciate any help with this.

Here is the full code, but you have to activate the functions in the console to see the problem. `randomMoves(num)` to set the random array for `showMoves()` to see the flashing lights where I'm having my problem.:

```js
const simonHTML = {
    power : document.querySelector('.powerButton'),
    strictButton : document.getElementById('strict'),
    startButton : document.getElementById('start'),
    displayScore : document.getElementById('score'),
    colors : document.getElementsByClassName('color')
  }
  
  const game = {
    on : false,
    start : false,
    strict : false,
    score : 0,
    computerMoves : [],
    playerMoves : [],
    colors : [greenBox = document.getElementById('green'), 
    blueBox = document.getElementById('blue'), 
    yellowBox = document.getElementById('yellow'), 
    redBox = document.getElementById('red')]
  }
  
  //move the purple div back and forth
  function turnOn () {
      if(!game.on){
        simonHTML.power.classList.add('moveRight');
        simonHTML.power.classList.remove('moveLeft')
        game.on = true;
        simonHTML.displayScore.textContent = game.score.toString();
    }  
    else if(game.on){ 
        simonHTML.power.classList.remove('moveRight');
        simonHTML.power.classList.add('moveLeft'); 
        game.on = false; 
        simonHTML.displayScore.textContent = '-';
    } 
  }

  function randomMoves (num) {
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
      let moves = game.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * game.colors.length)]
      game.computerMoves.push(moves);
    }
    return game.computerMoves;
  }

  function resetMoves () {
    game.computerMoves = [];
  }

const colors = [
  new Map([[green, "lime"], [yellow, "#FF6"], [blue, "dodgerblue"], [red, "salmon"]]),
  new Map([[green, "green"], [yellow, "#CC0"], [red, "red"], [blue, "blue"]])
];

const sounds = {
  green : new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3"),
  blue : new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3"),
  yellow : new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3"),
  red : new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3")
};

const colorFlashPeriod = 1000; // in ms

function showMoves() {
    let moveCounter = 0; 
    const timeoutCount = game.computerMoves.length * 2; 
    (function nextColor() {
        let move = game.computerMoves[moveCounter >> 1]; 
        let c = game.computerMoves[moveCounter]
        console.log(c.id);
        move.style.backgroundColor = colors[(moveCounter++) & 1].get(move);
        if (moveCounter < timeoutCount) { setTimeout(nextColor, colorFlashPeriod) }
    })();
}

function playerMoveDown(e){
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = colors[0].get(e.target);
  let color = e.target.id;
  sounds[color].play();
  return game.playerMoves.push(e.target);
}

function playerMoveUp(e){
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = colors[1].get(e.target);
}

for (let i = 0; i < simonHTML.colors.length; i++){
  simonHTML.colors[i].addEventListener('mousedown', playerMoveDown);
  simonHTML.colors[i].addEventListener('mouseup', playerMoveUp);
}
 

simonHTML.power.addEventListener('click', turnOn);
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.flex-row{
    width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

 .center-options{
    align-self:center;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
}

body{
    background-color: gray;
}

.centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.outer{
    height: 30em;
    width:30em;
    background-color:rgba(21, 56, 41, 1);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #222;
}

/*=============Color buttons=================*/

.color{
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    position: relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#green{
    background-color:green;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
    border-top: 10px solid;
    border-right:5px solid
}

#blue{
    background-color:blue;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%;
    border-right:5px solid
}

#yellow{
    background-color:rgb(204,204,0);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    border-top: 10px solid;
    border-left:5px solid;
}

#red{
    background-color:red;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
    border-left: 5px solid;
}

/*=============Controller=================*/

#controller{
    z-index: 1;
    height:14em;
    width:14em;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:gray;
    border: 10px solid;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction:column;
}

#controller h3{
    margin-top:1em;
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.options{
  margin-top: .5em;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}

.on-circle{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:red;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius:100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #222;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*===============off-on================*/

#onOff{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}

#onOff h4:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:20px;
}

#onOff h4:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-right:20px;
}

#onOff > div {
  height:2em;
  border-radius:10%;
  width:4em;
  background-color:#404040;
}

#onOff > div > div {
  height:100%;
  width:35%;
  background-color:purple;
  margin-left:1px;
  border-radius:10%;
  border:3px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.moveRight{
    transition: all .2s linear;
    transform: translateX(2.5em);
}

.moveLeft{
    transition: all .2s linear; 
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Simon Game</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='./main.css'>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='./simon.js' async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container outer centered'>
            <div id = 'blue' class= 'color shade'></div>
            <div id = 'red'  class= 'color shade'></div>
            <div id = 'controller' class='centered'>
                <h3>Simon</h3>
              <div class='options flex-row'>
                <div class='center-options'>
                    <h4>Score</h4>
                    <h5 id='score'>-</h5>
                </div>
                <div class='center-options'>
                  <h4>Start</h4>
                  <div id='start' class='on-circle'></div>
                </div>
                <div class='center-options'>
                  <h4>Strict</h4>
                  <div id='strict' class='on-circle'></div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div id='onOff' class='flex-row'>
               <h4>Off</h4>
               <div>
                 <div class='powerButton'></div>
               </div>
               <h4>On</h4>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div id = 'green'  class= 'color shade'></div>
            <div id = 'yellow'  class= 'color shade'></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please add fiddle /snippet for this ?

Comment: I just linked my codepen, but you have to activate the functions in the console to see the problem. randomMoves(num) to set the random array for showMoves() to see the flashing lights where I'm having my problem.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Please don't ask for Fiddles as those links can die over time. Code Snippets are the way to go.